# Select a radiobutton within a listitem in jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have the following code :

```
<li>
<span class="radio_appt">
<input id="color1" type="radio" name="ctl00$cph1$appointment" value="color1">
</span>
</li>
```

How do I select the INPUT element so that I can add a click event to it?

There are multiple listitem elements each with the same HTML wihtin as you can see above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why not do $('#color1') . id attribute should be unique

Comment: because the list is generated dynamically and I will have any number of "color" items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery selector:

```
$(".radio_appt input[type='radio']").change(function(e) {
    // Your function here
});
```

Note that you need a `change` event handler to respond to changes of the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `on` on a document object and passing the required selector for radio button. This way there will be only one event handler but listening to all the radio buttons matching the selector.

```
//Using attribute ends with selector
$(document).on('click', 'input[name$=appointment]', function(){
    //Code here for click event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the input element by its id if there is a unique id attribute for each of your input elements

```
    $('#color1').click(function(){ ....
     });
```

Comment: This won't work for my situation as "color1" is one of any number of items.  They are generated dynamically so I won't know how many there are at any time.